# Add addEventListener("click", f) on WASM

Tags: go, webassembly

I was able to add a button with n `onclick` action as below:

```golang
    var f js.Func
    f = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        defer f.Release()
        Window.Call("alert", "Hello World")
        // or
        // alert := Window.Get("alert")
        // alert.Invoke("Hello World")
        return nil
    })
    // f = function(){ alert("Hello World") };


    var Window = js.Global()
    // document = window.document
    document := Window.Get("document")
    // btn = document.createElement("button")
    btn := document.Call("createElement", "button")
    // btn.innerText = "Click me"
    btn.Set("innerText", "Click me")
    // btn.style.background='#000000';
    btn.Get("style").Call("setProperty", "background-color", "blue")
    // btn.onclick = f
    btn.Set("onclick", f)
    // document.body.appendChild(btn)
    document.Get("body").Call("appendChild", btn)
```

It worked perfectly, but I tried replicating JS code:

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function(event){  f });
```

As:

```golang
btn.Call("addEventListener", "click", f )
// or
btn.Call("addEventListener").Set("click", f)
```

But none of them worked, any idea why?